# how to call outer class function from inner function in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, class, oop

```
class Outer{
    private outFunction(){
       console.log("Okay!");
    }
    public functionWeCall(){
         function innerFunction(){
             this.outFunction();    //That doesn't work
         }
    }
}
```

I am trying to split the code into functions, for readability. But this doesnt work, how can I call an outer class function from an inner function?

Comment: Probably the reason is the outFunction is private.

Comment: @Chaz a local function defined inside a member function is part of the class and therefore can access private members

Comment: Privacy is also irrelevant. You simply have the wrong this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a matter of scope. When you get to `functionWeCall()`, `this` starts referring to that very function instead of to the class, thus `outFunction()` doesn't exist on `this`. A typical workaround might look like this:

```
class Outer {
  private outFunction() {
    console.log("Okay!");
  }

  public functionWeCall() {
    let _this = this;
    
    function innerFunction() {
        _this.outFunction();
    }
  }
}
```

... but I'd rather advice reworking the whole thing so that you don't have nested functions like that.

Edit: as suggested by @Aluan Haddad, here's the same thing, but with an arrow function:

```
class Outer {
  private outFunction() {
    console.log("Okay!");
  }

  public functionWeCall() {
    () => {
      this.outFunction();
    }
  }
}
```

... and if you want the inner function to still be callable, assign it to a variable:

```
class Outer {
  private outFunction() {
    console.log("Okay!");
  }

  public functionWeCall() {
    let innerFunction = () => {
      this.outFunction();
    }
    
    innerFunction(); // this could be anywhere in the scope of functionWeCall()
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't think of it as a workaround or something that should necessarily be refactored. Sometimes a nested function is exactly what you need. If you are going to use `this`, you commonly need to create functions that close over `this`, i.e. to pass to some other function, and such functions are by definition nested.

Comment: Thanks, adding 'this' inside the function would probably work as well but I think this case is problem, I can't divide my functions without declaring a temporary variable '_this'.

Comment: @Sahin, arrow functions, `=>`, were added to JavaScript because this is a common annoyance. Arrow functions don't have their own `this` so you can use it like you would any other variable inside one.